# What is ionic --project-id =<slug>?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

On Ionic Doc page: [ionic start](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/cli/commands/start#option-project-id)

There's these arguments to set upon creation of a new project.
English is not my mother language so I'm lost on translation, meaning and use of this particular argument:

```
--project-id =<slug>?
```

Anyone can explain it?

Comment: you can Ignore it. it is not necessary to use this argument.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thanks Najam :) As a matter of fact, I am. But can you explain it? I literally have no clue of what it does